# Why did so few early computers have video output?

Tags: history

Why was the serial terminal the dominant modality for interactive computer input and output up until the rise of desktop systems, with no earlier widespread adoption of the design later used by desktop systems, of the host system generating video signal for direct connection to a monitor?

Sources explain that early video terminals emerged as a replacement, in many cases a drop-in replacement, for teletypewriter-style terminals, later evolving to acquire features such as interactive editing and block transfer. However, no prominent examples appear of a minicomputer or microcomputer, predating the emergence of desktop system, that supplied video output directly to a display device, obviating the need for memory and processing on the peripheral.

Comment: What does "early computers" mean? Specifically until what year? I doubt there are "no examples".

Comment: @Laurel: Does the language given in the *body* of the question not adequately identify the relevant period?

Comment: I found a computer from ~1960 that does video output. No, it's not clear to me if I can post that as an answer.

Comment: @Laurel, I think if you would review the language of the question carefully, then your questions and quibbles would be likely to resolve.

Comment: Video output requires video memory to hold the data. 80x25 is 2k right there and RAM was very expensive

Comment: @epl `obviating the need for memory and processing on the peripheral`.  Well firstly early computers were extremely memory constrained.  The idea of just adding video without adding processor or RAM to handle seems really weird when the existing CPU and RAM were already maxed out just doing the computers "day job" of crunching numbers.

Comment: @epl  Secondly you're expecting two devices (a CPU and  digital to analogue encoder) share the same RAM. Attaching two devices to the same RAM doesn't work (it can't work).  In modern PCs that's the job of the [Northbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)).  These are very complex device by early standards. And remember how slow early electronics were.  Adding a memory controller would have *really* slowed down the CPU.

Comment: @Philip: Right, but adding a video terminal to the set of assets under common management and in a common location is not avoiding adding memory or processing capabilities, only placing those resources a separate unit. I am considering the tradeoffs in total of the host with a serial line to a video unit versus the host with a video line to a plain monitor (and keyboard).

Comment: @epl You seem to have re-defined your question several times over in your comments making it really unclear. It's good manners here to [edit] your question with clarifications otherwise people answer points in your comments and you then deny it was ever what you were asking.

Comment: But you might want to note the context such electronics.  The Telegraph was a machine which converted electrical signals into text or visa versa.  It had been in common use for more than 100 years by 1960.  So serial consoles (of a form) pre-dated computers massively.  You seem to be asking why wasn't the replacement invented sooner, or why was the replacement (at-first) a drop-in replacement?

Comment: @Philip: I noted that early video terminals were little more than drop-in replacements for teletypewriter-style terminals, later and incrementally acquiring interactive features. The curious observation is that up to the point that the size of some computers approached the size of consoles, there was no widespread use of video output from a host computer directly to a monitor. Yes, it makes sense that early terminals would repurpose equipment predating computers, but the following period had been one of fierce competition and rapid innovation.

Answer (score 9):

*[For this answer I assume that this is about micro computers, as it assumes the availability of terminals in general - something not given for real early machines]*

### TL;DR: No Use-Case Prior to Desktop Computers.

A desktop computer is the very definition of a computer with integrated video, as there was no use case for doing so before computers became small enough to be put on a desk. This is as well true for the very first desktop computers (Cugar C4, Datapoint 2200), as well as later all in one machines (PET, Apple, TRS)

In addition, the timeline between terminal introduction and desktop computer isn't as long as the question assumes. While

- first terminals were introduced in the mid-1960s

  - IBM 2260 in 1964 with 4 to 12 rows of 80 characters
- they didn't started to become common usage until the early 1970s.

  - IBM 3270 with 80 by 24 in 1971 and
  - [DEC VT05](http://terminals-wiki.org/wiki/index.php/DEC_VT05) with 20 lines at 72 characters each in 1971
- Which in turn produced the first desktop computers that come close to today's definition

  - Datapoint 2200 ind 1971
  - Cogar C4 in 1973
- It wasn't until 1974/75 that the future standards emerged

  - Hazeltine 1000 in 1974
  - DEC VT50 in 1975
- Which is as well the same time that microprocessors became used in terminals and, well, early micro computers.
- And it wasn't much later that the first all-in-one desktop apeared

  - Apple 1, 1976
  - Sol 20, 1976

Terminal usage as a mainstay are contemporary to desktop computers, not really prior. They as well had their best days during late 1970s to early 1990s. The sequence implied by the question simply didn't happen.

In the end, terminals are the use case where a central computer system handles concurrent users, more often than not in remote locations. That use case never vanished, except nowadays the 'terminals' are generic PCs at heart fitted with a terminal style keyboard (if at all) and running a terminal emulation.

Desktop computers are a use case where it's about a direct relation of single user of a single computer - essentially moving the central computer onto individual desks with only a simngle terminal attached - wich in turn got integrated right as well.

---

> Why was the serial terminal the dominant modality for interactive computer input and output up until the rise of desktop systems,

**Because terminals existed already**. Terminals are ready to use sub systems. It's already a noticeable effort to get a computer up and running, so why invest even more money and lengthen time to market by developing the whole world? Heck, the hardware needed for a terminal was usually at least as complex as the computer itself.

Think of the first cars. They were essentially gas engines packages in horse carriages (or made up from bicycle parts). For the first 30+ years, up until the 1920s, car frames were mostly based on horse carriages modified for internal steering - with wooden wheels and parabolic springs.

Same reason as with early micros: Technology and parts was proven and available and good enough. Same with

Further, while it looks obvious from today's point of view, **it wasn't really clear that a computer would need a CRT at all** - Text I/O is a very specific use case. Going by the sheer numbers, the overwhelming of computers do not need one today - just think about all the processors stuck in anything from Furbys to CNC machinery. That was - and still is - what microprocessor developers had in mind. Desktop usage is only a very tiny fraction of the market - one that had to develop first.

Beside embedded, the microprocessor was seen as either to be used *in* a terminal, or as a computer operated by a terminal - like all computers before.

**Next, there is flexibility**. Why narrowing down usability to a certain I/O configuration, when the customer can select between dozends of different capable terminals?

Oh, and, as so often, **there is of course the price part**. Before cheap integrated video circuitry, adding video might have doubled or tripled the price of a basic unit. It doesn't make no sense to ask a higher price while narrowing the capabilities offered.

> with no earlier widespread adoption of the design later used by desktop systems, of the host system generating video signal for direct connection to a monitor?

There were. Either very early ones, or very special ones, but in general, it was already a serious issue to build a computer.

> no prominent examples appear of a minicomputer

For minis it's even more useless to have embedded video. After all, a major use case (beside control/embedded again) was support of multiple users, each needing his own display and keyboard - sounds exactly like the description of a terminal, doesn't it?

> or microcomputer, predating the emergence of desktop system,

It's helpful to keep in mind that desktop systems came *before* micro computer and they came as well with build in display and keyboard. Think Cogar C4 and Datapoint 2200. Sure, the were sold as terminals, but that was rather due the fact that noone would buy a desktop computer when he had a mainframe to work with. same reason why a DEC was sold as their machines not as computers but Programmable Data Processors. Kind of a chicken and egg situation back then :))

In fact, history repeated itself. Two more prominent early microcomputers with build in display were as well explicte aroudn the idea to operate as terminal, but could be stand alone computers as well: The Apple I and the SOL.

> that supplied video output directly to a display device,

Which would be still a device to be added wouldn't it?

> obviating the need for memory and processing on the peripheral.-

But creating the need to have that very memory within the computer - plus adding memory constrains, as now the/each video controller needs to access that memory concurently with the CPU. Plus adding the need to spend CPU time to do terminal work - like scrolling.

**Putting video memory inside CPU memory space is a cost cutting measure payed for with rare resources like CPU performance and memory allocation.** In additon it increases cost of early systems which often had not much more memory than the terminal connected.

There is no real advantage by having a display memory within a computer, or even worse, within the primary address space of it's CPU. Doing so is a real bad case of resource waste. A PDP-11 can address 64 KiB, if it had to hold 4 KiB for each user for display data (80x24 plus attributes), there wouldn't be much room left for programs or data when serving more than one user. Using a terminal externalizes this cost. One program can serve a dozend users or more with 64 KiB RAM as long as they are connected via a terminal.

And no, accessing screen data isn't really something done often enough to make spending 1/16th of your address space a good idea. Doing so only made sense for single user systems and even then it was quite limiting.

Putting it into memory was only a trick done by *cheap* micros to reduce cost.Who cares for usability if it sells?

Having display memory within CPU address space became several times a bottleneck to be fought with. Holding a highres picture in an Apple II or C64 needed 8 KiB of only 64 possible. With the PC it got worse, despite having 1 MiB of address space, already VGA needed to add paging to allow access to higher resolutions. It got for short time relieved with 32 bit address space, just to run into issues a few years later again - and by now it's external again ... in fact, again via a serial line. Given, PCIe is a bit faster than RS232, still funny, isn't it?

---

Long story short: There was neither a need nor a use case nor the intention to build such a very specific integrated device as first application.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134315/discussion-on-answer-by-raffzahn-why-did-so-few-early-computers-have-video-outpu).

Answer (score 5):

> Why are there no examples of video output in early computers?

But there is.

The [operator console for the CDC 6600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6000_series#Peripheral_processors) had direct video output of text.

While the CDC 6600 is not a minicomputer by any stretch of the imagination, it certainly qualifies as an 'early computer', being a 1960s machine.  And the CDC 6600 is very definitely prominent in the history of computers.

The display was actually attached to a peripheral processor, one of the 10 PPs that handle all I/O on the system -- the main 6600 CPU is dedicated to running user jobs; the PPs run device drivers and most of what you'd call the "operating system".

Each PP would qualify as a minicomputer: 12-bit word, 4K words of memory.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The original language was clumsy. The intention was to ask why the terminal dominated earlier, against the design of an integrated video adapter that eventually would become commonplace only as desktop systems emerged.

Answer (score 4):

In the 1960s and 1970s there were a few companies whose main focus was graphic display.  One such company was Evans And Sutherland.  [See their early history](https://ohiostate.pressbooks.pub/graphicshistory/chapter/13-3-evans-and-sutherland/).

A digital graphics subsystem was much larger and more expensive than an entire computer would be in 1982.  It would only make sense in an environment where graphics was mission critical.

The PDP-1 computer from DEC, first built in 1960, also had an optional display.  This is where the [original spacewar](https://youtu.be/1EWQYAfuMYw)
was presented.

Comment: Are you equating graphics support to a video terminal for display of text?

Comment: Video signal to a monitor sounds like graphics to me.  Was that not intended?

Comment: I'm not suggesting your terminology is wrong, just ambiguous, and perhaps in this case equivocating. You reference a graphical game, implying the strict sense of graphics, in having visual features beyond mere text. The subject of the question is simply a video signal rasterized from a text buffer, applying a small set of builtin glyphs. Such capability is a good deal simpler than full graphics, as evidenced by the observation that it was provided by video terminals of the earliest designs.

Comment: @epl No, graphics were available on computers _before_ text display. First CRT usage on computers was graphics only - for text printing terminals was the way to go.

Comment: @Raffzahn: It's not relevant. The question rests on two uncontroversial premises. First, that the video terminal dominated user interaction for a considerable period, of at least a decade. Second, that that period eventually ended, with the integration of video adapters into the computer bus and chassis. The question is why the latter transition had not occurred until roughly the time of emergence of the machine class known as desktop systems.

Comment: @epl The premises are made up. Maybe the confusion is because integration of video might be the very definition of what you call a desktop computer - making your question rather self serving? Before the microcomputer there was no desktop computer, and before the desktop computer no (generic) use case for integrated video. Computers were large and in remote places (computing centers), users were connected via serial lines. It makes no sense to lay video cable (and keyboard cabling) over several hundred meters.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The question is why the integration occured so late after the emergence of video terminals. The terms simply refer to historic developments. Answering the question only by appealing to their meanings is circular. Also, video cabling extending far beyond several hundred meters had already become commonplace in other industries.

Comment: @epl An integration only makes sense when the computer is not remote. But before the micro computer computers were always remote. Video cabling would way more expensiv while delivering way lower quality than local video (we're talking 80 characters, not TV) - and needed in addition to keyboard cabling. In computer video generation makes only sense with a local computer.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Sure, I concede that many deployment scenarios would have made terminals economical, desirable, and even essential, but surely many others would have situated the console at very little distance from a mini or micro chassis.

Comment: @epl Name some that need that would justify the cost of extra development for such a rare case, one that is not about very special situations like vector graphics or real time signal processing.  Further considering that serial terminals only really showed up after 1970 and wide spread use only started ca. 1972/73 (IBM 3270 in 1972 DEC VT50 in 1975) , not really decades before all in one micros like SOL/Apple/Tandy in 1976/77. (Development cycles were way shorter back then than today - having no installed base gives freedom)